# Smallest closed subspace of $A$ in pre-Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let be $A\subset H$ a subset of $H$ Hilbert space. I know that $A^{\perp\perp}$ is the smallest closed subspace of $H$, such that $A\subset A^{\perp\perp}$.

But if $H$ is a inner product space (or pre-Hilbert, i.e., not necessarily complete), can I say something about this? $A^{\perp\perp}$ is the smallest closed subspace of $H$, such that $A\subset A^{\perp\perp}$?

Anyone has a counterexample?

---

With help of @user1952009, I tried something. Let be $H^{'}$ the completed Hilbert space of $H$ and $F\subset H^{'}$ closed subspace, such that $A\subset F$. Then, $A^{\perp\perp}\subset F^{\perp\perp}=F\subset H^{'}$.

So I need to show that $F\cap H$ is closed subspace in $H$ to conclude, cause the hypothesis is **smallest closed subspace of $H$**.

Ok so far?

Comment: closed $\implies$ complete so $A^{\perp}$ and $A^{\perp \perp}$ are Hilbert spaces. now considering the Hilbert space obtained from $H$ by completing it, you retrieve in the 1st situation ?

Comment: @user1952009: closed only implies complete if the "surrounding space" (in which we consider closedness) is itself complete.

Comment: @user1952009 to (closed $\implies$ complete) I need that $H$ be complete. That doesn't work.

Comment: ok $A^\perp = \{ x \in H | \forall a \in A : \langle x, a \rangle = 0 \} $ ? so consider $B = A^{\perp \perp}$ and $B' = A^{\perp \perp}$ in the completed hilbert space, and write that $B = B' \cap H$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not sure that I understood what you say, let me try here. Let be $F\subset H^{'}$ (Complement of $H$) closed subspace, such that $A\subset F$. Then, $A^{\perp\perp}\subset F^{\perp\perp}=F\subset H^{'}$. But I need that $F\subset H$ to conclude, or not? (Hypothesis: **smallest closed subspace of $H$**